# How to break out of nested loops in functions (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

A lot of answers I've read is without functions. However, I absolutely need to include in functions in my script.

```
var input = require('readline-sync')
var cart = [];
function func2() {
    console.log("this is the inner function")
    while (true) {
        firstinput = input.questionInt('Please Enter your input (1, 2, 3). Press 0 to Go back to outermost loop. You will still be in the program.')
        switch (firstinput) {
            case 0: 
                break; //breaks out of this entire func2()
            case 1: 
                func3()
                break; //breaks, but goes back to firstinput
            case 2:
                func4() //im not going to define it here, but similar to func3()
                func5() //im not going to define it here, but similar to func3()
                break;
            case 3:
                func5() 
                func3() //as you can see, the functions are recurring
                break;
            default:
                console.log('Input valid number, please')
                continue;
        }
    }
}

function func3() {

    while (true) {
        secondinput = input.question("Hi, please pick 1a, 1b, or 1c! You can Press 0 to exit to the outermost function. YOu will still be in the program, though")
        switch (secondinput) {
            case '0':
                break; //breaks out of func3() and func2()
            case '1a':
                cart.push("1a")
                break; //breaks out of func3()
            case '1b':
                cart.push("1b")
                break; //breaks out of func3()
            case '1c':
                cart.push('1c')
                break; //breaks out of func3()
            default:
                console.log('invalid input')
                continue;
        }
        
    }
}
function func1() {
    while (true) {
        func2()
        if ((secondinput == 0) || (firstinput == 0)) {
            console.log("I see you've pressed 0. Let's loop through again")
        }
        else {
            console.log('Here is what was in your cart: ' + cart)
        }
    }

}

func1()
```

I hope this was clear! I need to break out of inner functions and outer functions. this is hard because if I changed a value of a variable in a function, the value outside doesn't change.

Thank you in advance

my question is: When I get inside func3(), how do I break out of everything if I press '0'?

Comment: Using `break` in this manner should only break the current loop. I could not believe that `break` behaves differently in your `switch` at func2.

Answer (score 0):

You can return when you want stop the function, or *continue* to keep loop going.

```
while (true) {
    firstinput = input.questionInt('Please Enter your input (1, 2, 3). Press 0 to Go back to outermost loop. You will still be in the program.')
    switch (firstinput) {
        case 0: 
            return; //breaks out of this entire func2()
        case 1: 
            func3()
            continue; //breaks, but goes back to firstinput
        case 2:
            func4()
            func5() 
            continue;
        case 3:
            func5() 
            func3() //as you can see, the functions are recurring
            continue;
        default:
            console.log('Input valid number, please')
            continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I get inside func3(), how do I press 0 to go back right to the beginning though?

Comment: case 0: return func1();

Answer (score 0):

You should use combination of return/break/continue as here

```js
// var input = require('readline-sync')
var cart = [];
let firstinput, secondinput;
function func2() {
    console.log("this is the inner function")
    while (true) {
        firstinput = +prompt('Please Enter your input (1, 2, 3). Press 0 to Go back to outermost loop. You will still be in the program.')
        console.log({firstinput})
        switch (firstinput) {
            case 0: 
                return; //breaks out of this entire func2()
            case 1: 
                func3()
                break; //breaks, but goes back to firstinput
            case 2:
                func4() //im not going to define it here, but similar to func3()
                func5() //im not going to define it here, but similar to func3()
                break;
            case 3:
                func5() 
                func3() //as you can see, the functions are recurring
                break;
            case 4: // show cart
            case -1: // exit everything
                return;
            default:
                console.log('Input valid number, please')
                continue;
        }
    }
}

function func3() {

    while (true) {
        secondinput = prompt("Hi, please pick 1a, 1b, or 1c! You can Press 0 to exit to the outermost function. YOu will still be in the program, though")
        switch (secondinput) {
            case '0':
                return false; //breaks out of func3()
            case '1a':
                cart.push("1a")
                return true; //breaks out of func3()
            case '1b':
                cart.push("1b")
                return true; //breaks out of func3()
            case '1c':
                cart.push('1c')
                return true; //breaks out of func3()
            default:
                console.log('invalid input')
                continue;
        }
        
    }
}
function func1() {
    while (true) {
        func2()
        if ((secondinput == 0) || (firstinput == 0)) {
            console.log("I see you've pressed 0. Let's loop through again")
        } else if(firstinput === -1) {
          return
        }
        else {
            console.log('Here is what was in your cart: ' + cart)
        }
    }

}

func1()
```

You can also use labeled break to exit a block like this

```js
let i=0
a: while(true){
  ++i
  switch(i) {
    case 4:
      break a; // break the while loop
    default:
      console.log(i);
  }
}
// prints
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

For more information on labelled break, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i need the functions, so i need it coded in a way that if i press 0 in func3() [which is the inner function of the INNER function], it goes all the way to the outermost loop and prints "I see you've pressed 0. Let's loop through again"